# Monotouch binding

Tags: iphone, binding, xamarin.ios, bugsense

I'm trying to bind BugSense to Monotouch. But I have some problems, and now I will hear if someone here will check my bindings?

The BugSense Header look like this:

```
#define BUGSENSE_LOG(__EXCEPTION, __TAG) [BugSenseCrashController logException:__EXCEPTION withTag:__TAG]

OBJC_EXPORT @interface BugSenseCrashController : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>

+ (BugSenseCrashController *) sharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey:(NSString *)APIKey;

+ (BugSenseCrashController *) sharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey:(NSString *)APIKey 
                                                userDictionary:(NSDictionary *)userDictionary;

+ (BugSenseCrashController *) sharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey:(NSString *)APIKey 
                                                userDictionary:(NSDictionary *)userDictionary
                                               sendImmediately:(BOOL)immediately;

+ (BOOL) logException:(NSException *)exception withTag:(NSString *)tag;

@end
```

I have then added an binding projekt and in my ApiDefinition.cs wrote:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface  BugSenseCrashController 
{
    [Static]
    [Export ("sharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey:")]
    BugSenseCrashController SharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey(String APIKey);

    [Static]
    [Export ("sharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey:userDictionary:")]
BugSenseCrashController SharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey(String APIKey, [NullAllowed] NSDictionary userDictionary);

    [Static]
    [Export ("sharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey:userDictionary:sendImmediately:")]
    BugSenseCrashController SharedInstanceWithBugSenseAPIKey(string APIKey, [NullAllowed] NSDictionary userDictionary, bool immediately);

    [Static]
    [Export ("sharedInstance")]
    BugSenseCrashController SharedInstance();

    [Static]
    [Export ("logException:withTag:")]
    bool LogException (NSException exception, string tag);
}
```

My problem is the "UIAlertViewDelegate" in the Header. I can’t do a “[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]” in Monotouch.

Anyone how can help?

The problem is to bind BugSense to Monotouch. I created a Monotouch binding library, took the binary file from BugSenseiOS.Framework, named it bugsense.a and added it to the binding project. But it dosn't work.

My "LinkWith":

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libBugSense-iOS.a", LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.Thumb | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks="SystemConfiguration", LinkerFlags = "-lz")]
```

BugSense need SystemConfiguration.framework and libz.dylib.

Link to BugSense
http://www.bugsense.com/docs/ios

Comment: Do you have a typo?  `My problem is the .`

Comment: mmm whats your problem??

Comment: Sorry some parts of my question was missing. Have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a crash reporter, keep in mind that crash reporters interfere with Mono's own exception handling, so they dont work, even if you bind them.

Comment: Okay, so you can't use any crash reporters with monotouch? Do you now if they have their own?